# How do i render a template inside another template?

Tags: python, django, templates, url

I'm new in Django and Python and I'm stuck! It's complicated to explain but I will give it a try... I have my `index.html` template with an include tag:

```
{% include 'menu.inc.html' %}
```

The menu is a dynamic (http://code.google.com/p/django-treemenus/). The menu-app holds a view that renders `menu.inc.html`:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import Context, loader
from treemenus.models import Menu

def mymenu(request):
    mainmenu = Menu.objects.get(id = 1)
    template = loader.get_template('menu.inc.html')
    context = Context({
        'mainmenu':mainmenu,
    })

    return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

So when I access `index.html` the server will serve it to me and django will load and serve `menu.inc.html`! But not the content! My question is:

1. How do I reverse link the menu.inc.html to the view?! or
2. How do I tell django that a template needs a rendered template by a specific view?!

I don't want put `mainmenu = Menu.objects.get(id = 1)` in my index's view because the menu will be on other pages too ... I was thinking iframes + rule in the `urls.py`, but that's an ugly workaround ...

Do I make any sense?!

Comment: Please read the formatting instructions to the right -- you need to indent your code for it to be marked up as code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first blush this seems to be a case for adding an [inclusion tag](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags). You might want to write a custom tag that renders the tree menu. From the main view you can then pass the necessary context variables for this tag to work.

From the documentation:

> Another common type of template tag is the type that displays some data by rendering another template.